# ASP.NET Identity 2.0 with ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-identity

I have a ASP.NET MVC 2 project which I could open in VS 2012. But for that project I want to add asp.net identity 2.0. Is ASP.NET mvc 5 mandatory for asp.net identity? As far as I understood can't we separate the UI part from the user store/authentication methods hence there wont be any dependency on mvc 5. If there is any steps which I could follow for using asp.net mvc 2 with identity, please provide advice or the link to read further or any other advice about migration steps.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is ASP.NET mvc 5 mandatory for asp.net identity?

No, you do not need ASP.Net MVC5 for ASP.NET Identity 2.0.

**However, ASP.NET Identity 2.0 requires .Net 4.5.**

> please provide advice or the link to read further or any other advice
>   about migration steps

Here is the [Migrating an Existing Website from SQL Membership to ASP.NET Identity Version 1](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity).

***Note:*** Identity V1 is a little bit different from Identity V2, but not much.

Comment: Thanks Win, I am looking into the article.

Comment: Did anyone tried/working with the above kind of scenario, if yes could you please explain.

Comment: Convert your MVC2 Application to .Net 4.5. Then install NuGet packages like [this example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/20/test-announcing-rtm-of-asp-net-identity-2-0-0.aspx). If you encounter a specific error, please create a separate question.